# Discrepancy measure for bayesian beta model

Tags: r, jags

I fitted a beta model with a vector of Jaccard similarities as response variable and a vector of euclidean distances as predictor variable in JAGS.

I coded the model as follows:

```
model {
  b0 ~ dnorm(0.0,0.001)
  b1 ~ dnorm(0.0,0.001)
  b2 ~ dnorm(0.0,0.001)
  b3 ~ dnorm(0.0,0.001)
  phi ~ dgamma(0.1,0.1)

    for (i in 1:n) {
    Y[i] ~ dbeta(alpha[i],beta[i])
    alpha[i] <- mu[i]*phi
    beta[i] <- (1 - mu[i])*phi
    logit(mu[i]) <- b0 + b1*X1[i] + b2*pow(X1[i],2) + b3*pow(X1[i],3)

    Ynew[i] ~ dbeta(alpha[i],beta[i])
    d[i]<-  (Y[i] - (mu[i]*phi))/sqrt((mu[i]+0.01)*phi*(1-(mu[i]-0.01)))
    dnew[i]<- (Ynew[i] - (mu[i]*phi))/sqrt((mu[i]+0.01)*phi*(1-(mu[i]-0.01)))
    d2[i]<- pow(d[i],2)  
    dnew2[i]<- pow(dnew[i],2) 

    d2[i]<- pow(d[i],2)  
    dnew2[i]<- pow(dnew[i],2) 
    }
  p.fit<-sum(d2[]) 
  p.fitnew<-sum(dnew2[])
}
```

Deviance and DIC are both resulting in negative values.
And the discrepancy measures, resulted from the comparison among Pearson's Chi-square residuals, show a perfect fit, which I suspect are unreal.
In addition, standard deviations, and standard errors for that instance are too narrow.

I would be glad if someone could point me to the right direction in modeling this regression and obtaining proper measures of deviance, DIC, Bayes-p and Lack of Fit.

Comment: Sorry if I am being obtuse here...
What quantity are you calculating with
d[i]<-  (Y[i] - (mu[i]*phi))/sqrt((mu[i]+0.01)*phi*(1-(mu[i]-0.01)))

Comment: No need to excuses, dear Jacob Socolar! I am calculating the Pearson's Chi Squared Residual for the predicted in d and for ideal datasetes in dnew. At least, I think I am doing that...

Comment: I don't think this expression yields Pearson's residual.  Pearson's residuals are given by the data minus the expectation, divided by the square root of the variance.  The expectation and variance of the beta-distribution are given correctly on the Wikipedia page for that distribution...
To make your life easier, there is no need for you to formulate these in terms of your nodes mu and phi--just use your nodes alpha and beta!

Comment: Thank you very much, Jacob Socolar! I will do it and post the results later for your appraisal.